# applying noreturn attribute to macro function call

Tags: c, gcc

I have macro like this:

```
#define error_exit(format, ...) \
    error_at_line(EXIT_FAILURE, 0, __FILE__, __LINE__, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

that I use to as a general fatal error function. Unfortunately, error_at_line doesn't have the noreturn gcc attribute because if you specify 0 as the first argument it does return. This causes problems, specifically, I get uninitialized variable warnings because gcc can't figure out that error_exit will never return.

For example:

```
int x;
switch(...) {
    case VALID:
        x = 1;
        break;
    default:
        error_exit(...);
}
return x;
```

gives me warning. So, how can I go about apply noreturn to a macro or even specific function invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming GCC ≥ 4.5.0,

```
#define error_exit(format, ...) \
    do { \
        error_at_line(EXIT_FAILURE, 0, __FILE__, __LINE__, format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        __builtin_unreachable(); \
    } while (0)
```

Comment: I ended up using a pragma to disable the warning on the affected line of code, but this seems like a good solution too

Answer (score 2):

The only sensible way is to create a new function that calls `error_at_line` that is marked `noreturn`. A macro cannot be marked `noreturn`, nor can a function that sometimes returns.

Instead of a `#define`, use an inline function to wrap the function, and mark it `noreturn`.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of the _at_line part of `error_at_line`.

Comment: You'll have to write the LINE macro so it gets evaluated where you need it to be evaluated. Yeah, it's a pain.

Comment: How does one write such a macro?

Comment: Pass the line to the noreturn function as a parameter and put `__LINE__` in the outer macro that calls the function.